# Views in Django with arbitrary number of url parameters

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I want to write universal View with Django, in this function i want to handle several situations: first when i have url like vkusers3/11122233/1/2/ and also i want it working when 2 or third arguments is missing in url, like: vkusers3/11122233/   or vkusers3/11122233/1/

I cannot find it tutorials how to do that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/ etc). 
The problem that this became a nightmare when you have more than 5 combinations in url parameters, then you should write 5 different url configurations, 5 times in html template hardcode this pattern.

BUT wait, even more!, what about combinatorics: i want /user/group/sex/smoking/ but also i want /user/group/smoking/  i.e. all users from group who is smoking of both man and woman. So the number is huge.

```
def list_groupmembers_sex(request, group_id, sex=None, smoking=None):
    success = False

    if group_id and sex and smoking==None:
        vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find({"member_of_group": int(group_id), 'sex': int(sex)})# 62740364 81099158
        success = True
    elif group_id and sex and smoking!=None:
        vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find({"member_of_group": int(group_id), 'sex': int(sex), 'personal.smoking': int(smoking)})
        success = True      
    else:
        vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find({'personal.smoking': 1})

    ctx = {'vkuser_list': vkusers, 'group_id': group_id, 'sex': sex, 'smoking':smoking, 'success': success}
    return render_to_response('blog/vkuser_list.html', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In my urls.py:

```
url(r'^vkusers3/(\d{1,8})/(\d{1})/(\d{1})/$', 'blog.views.list_groupmembers_sex', name='vkuser-list3'),
```

In my base.html:

```
<li class="menu-level-1"><a href="{% url 'vkuser-list3' group_id sex smoking %}">users</a></li>
```

Django 1.6.10, MongoDB 2.7.1, mongoengine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, you should probably bite the bullet and just go for query parameters - `vkusers3/?sex=1&smoking=2&group= 11122233`. You can drop the parameters completely from the URL and the view definition, and just use `request.GET['sex']` etc in the view body.

Comment: yes, this works! thanx, surprisingly i used simple if 'men' in self.request.GET but did not know how to get parameters

Answer (score 1):

You don't need so hairy logic.  Just populate the search critera with arguments passed to the view like this:

```
criteria = {}
if group_id:
    criteria['member_of_group'] = int(group_id)
if sex:
    criteria['sex'] = int(sex)
if smoking:
    criteria['personal.smoking'] = int(smoking)
vkusers = Vkuser._get_collection().find(criteria)
```

And yes, consider to switch to the regular GET parameters like @daniel-roseman suggested.  With urls like in your question you can't determine the `/user/group/sex/` url from the `/user/group/smoking/`.

**UPDATE**: `request.GET` is a dict-like object so you can use the `in` expression:

```
if 'sex' in request.GET:
    criteria['sex'] = int(request.GET['sex'])
```

Comment: this is cool approach of constructing dict in query! and it works, but if i do if request.GET['sex']:
        criteria['sex'] = int(request.GET['sex'])   it throws an error when second parameter (sex) is not specified in url, for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/vkusers2/?group=81099158. Error: MultiValueDictKeyError at /post/vkusers2/